# Floating header with sticky footer

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a floating header. content area and then a sticky footer.

http://jsfiddle.net/9vB5m/ it seems to be working here

http://jsfiddle.net/9vB5m/2/ covers up the footer....

Not sure why. Once i get this working. I'm then going to try to use this on my real layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to set css margin-bottom property for footer to 0.

Working code: http://jsfiddle.net/9vB5m/4/

Comment: Cant really argue as @Keverw accepted, but that isn't a sticky footer though.

Comment: Try it, it would nvr stick out :)

Comment: Whats happening with the footer now is a common thing.  http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ - This is what _sticky footer_ is